# Does Deadpool's mutation enhance his sense of humor as a side effect?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

Has it ever been shown in comics or movies whether Deadpool’s mutation that gives him the healing factor also enhances his sense of humor?

Bullets (pun intended):

- (It has been proven, beyond doubt that) stress affects one’s immune system.
- (Conventional wisdom and/or science says that) laughter is a great stress-buster. With that in mind, and healing factor being a **mutation**, would it not make sense for the mutation to enhance the sense of humor, in order to prevent stress, in order to prevent weakening of immune system, in order to enhance regenerative capabilities?

So the question essentially is, does Deadpool’s mutation enhance his sense of humor as a side effect? Or, is that just a coincidence?

Comment: Doesn't it depend a bit on how you define it? He doesn't get the humor because he gets the powers. He gets the humor because he's trying to cope with the pain of HAVING those powers

Comment: Define what? Humor? I think humor is an absolute concept. Sure, one person's humor might not be the same for another person, but I wouldn't agree that "he gets the humor as he is trying to cope with the PAIN of having the powers". I have rather had the impression that humor, in general, exists for no reason, and even more so in case of Deadpool. Or, where would you find a merc joking around while shooting bullets all around (and dodging some)?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time. Riddler and the Joker, and to some extent even TwoFace became more... humorous in order to cope with their pain (emotional)

Comment: Does that have any basis in science? Or has that same point been illustrated for Deadpool in movies or comics?

Comment: I'd say having the power puts Deadpool into situations that enable him to be snarky. Without the power, he wouldn't have as many opportunities to practice his dark humor because he wouldn't be killing bad guys with guns or puns. No power. Less chances to wise off. So, yes. His mutation enhances his sense of humor. It doesn't, however, make him funnier.

Comment: That's a pretty good theory. It even sounds more realistic. @MajorStackings

Comment: Isn't Deadpool's healing factor somehow coming from Wolverine? Wolverine isn't really known as the funniest character...

Comment: I take exception to the comment that "humor, in general, exists for no reason".  Humor is *absolutely* a coping mechanism and arguably a survival feature as it can combat some forms of stress and depression before they get worse.  This article is on laughter itself, but relevant: http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/culturebox/features/2014/the_humor_code/why_do_humans_laugh_the_evolutionary_biology_of_laughter.html

Answer (score 6):

*In the movie, he was already very funny and sarcastic before he got his powers.*

In comics, he was funny and sarcastic as well even if his mutation was not around to change him. He explained his procedure in a dramatic way:

[image]

He was being realistic while explaining it with sarcastic narrating.

Also in Deadpool #54 and #55, Wade gets a serum which negated his healing powers (forcing the mutation to retreat) and made him *mortal*. But in return he got his handsome looks again:

[image]

[image]

He was still sarcastic and funny after he lost his powers.